# Animating a 3D Model on Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d

I'm about to start writing a 3D model importer for Android which require to support animation.

I was looking around, and the best format i found is Collada, which seems to be the easiest to parse and the most complete/documented.

Before starting, I just wanted to have your opinions about it, is there something better/something wrong with Collada?

The idea is to do skeletal animation on Android (Im using OpenGL ES 2.0).

Thanks for your advices!

Answer (score 2):

I personally think that .vtk is one of the easiest 3D formats to parse in Java/Android and use in OpenGL-ES (I have created an app that contains a custom built parser to import the data from standard, legacy-ASCII .vtk file). The .vtk files that I use are generated using ITK-snap and VTK, from CT images of patients.

If you are planning to make 3D models from scratch, you should try using Sketchup. If you get Sketchup pro (either as a trial for one month, or a full purchase), you can convert your Sketchup 3D models directly to a large variety of 3D formats (including .obj). I would then advise you to download Paraview, which is a great piece of software for visualizing 3D data. In Paraview, open your .obj model, and then save the data as a .vtk file, so that you can use parse it in your app.